# How do I find userid by login (Python under *NIX)

Tags: python, linux, unix, process-management

I need to set my process to run under 'nobody', I've found os.setuid(), but how do I find `uid` if I have `login`?

I've found out that uids are in /etc/passwd, but maybe there is a more pythonic way than scanning /etc/passwd. Anybody?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [pwd](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) module in the python stdlib, for example:

```
import pwd
pw = pwd.getpwnam("nobody")
uid = pw.pw_uid
```

it uses /etc/passwd (well, technically it uses the posix C API, so I suppose it might work on an OS if it didn't use /etc/passwd but exposed the needed functions) but is cleaner than parsing it manually

Comment: Note that using pwd.getpwnam works correctly even when /etc/passwd points to external mechanisms (think a line with a single "+" in /etc/passwd) like LDAP.

Answer (score 5):

Never directly scan `/etc/passwd`.

For instance, on a Linux system I administer, the user accounts are not on `/etc/passwd`, but on a LDAP server.

The correct way is to use `getpwent`/`getgrent` and related C functions (as in @TFKyle's answer), which will get the information on the correct way for each system (on Linux glibc, it reads `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to know which NSS dynamic libraries to load to get the information).